# Equation with Absolute Value Functions in the Powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function, absolute-value

I am a Grade 12 student and I was unable to even properly approach the problem given below so I would love some pointers!

$2^{|x+1|} - 2^x = |2^x - 1| + 1$

First, I tried to assume $2^x$ as 't' and then tried to assume $2^{|x+1|}$ as t. Then, I tried squaring it up, taking logarithms on both sides but none proved fruitful. Finally, I went with graphing it which was a bit tedious and difficult without using Desmos/graphing calculators.

I would like a method that doesn't use graphing as graphing felt a bit time-consuming for me. If possible after guiding me with a method, if you could propose a more complex question in the same topic that I could solve would be highly appreciated.

Also, I am new to this forum so apologies for any errors.

Comment: Consider the cases $x<-1$, $x\in[-1,0]$ and $x>0$ separately. Then you can omit the absolut values and the equation should simplify.

Comment: How did you determine that those specific cases must be considered? As I wish to know how to find which cases should I consider so that I can reproduce the same idea in a different question.

Comment: @Aadhavan You can make this apparent by making a piecewise definition for the functions within the absolute value function

Comment: @Filthyscrub I have to do a piecewise definition for each of the absolute value functions, right?

Comment: @Aadhavan Yes, this this is done by noting that for example, for the function $|x+1|$ the function within the absolute value $x+1$ is equal to zero when $x=-1$, any value greater than -1 hence will be positive but any value less than -1 will lead to the function within the absolute value becoming negative hence we define it as $$|x+1|=\begin{cases}x+1 & x>-1\\ -(x+1) & x<-1 \\ \end{cases}$$

Comment: @Filthyscrub But, how do you combine the two absolute value parts to arrive at the conclusion of those 3 cases? Like $|2^x - 1| =  2^x - 1  when  x>= 0  and  -2^x +1  
 when  x < 0$

Comment: @Aadhavan try drawing out the cases for both the absolute value parts on a number line and see the overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be having trouble visualizing the three cases, as @Khosrotash has stated the process on finding the zeroes for the absolute functions and hence solving the problem, I shall limit this post as a complementary insight on how the three cases are found.

[image: Cases]

As you should be able to see from the diagram, the cases arise from finding the overlapping regions on the real number line between the possible values of $x$ from the piecewise functions of both the absolute value functions.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE. You can take apart for $x=-1,x=1$
because  of the roots  $$2^{|x+1|}\to |x+1|=0 \to x+1=0\to x=-1$$
and $$|2^x-1|=0\to 2^x-1=0 \to 2^x=1 \to x= 0$$
$$\begin{cases}x<-1 & 2^{|x+1|} - 2^x = |2^x - 1| + 1\\-1 \leq x \leq 0 & 2^{|x+1|} - 2^x = |2^x - 1| + 1\\ x>0 & 2^{|x+1|} - 2^x = |2^x - 1| + 1\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}x<-1 & 2^{-x-1} - 2^x = -2^x +1 + 1& x=-2\\-1 \leq x \leq 0 & 2^{x+1} - 2^x = -2^x +1 + 1& x=0\\ x>0 & 2^{x+1} - 2^x = 2^x-1 + 1 & x\in ]0,\infty[\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! But how did you determine to take it apart for $x = -1 , x = 1$ ?

Comment: I made some typos...I am sorry, I coorect it

Comment: I am sorry but it's a bit confusing for me, can you elucidate it a bit simpler and clearer? Like just because you got two roots $(x=1, x=-1)$ how do you determine the three cases

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\left(x\right)=2^{\left|x+1\right|}-2^x$ and $g\left(x\right)=\left|2^x-1\right|+1$.

[image]

The solution set to $2^{\left|x+1\right|}-2^x=\left|2^x-1\right|+1$ is $x=\left\{-2,0,\mathbb{R}^+\right\}$.